# My game board loops endlessly

Tags: c, loops, count

I have an issue with my game board looping endlessly. Any three letters in a row are removed and the process is continued until there are no more letters left. It is supposed stop running when the characters run out but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help?

***EDIT***: The problem appears to be in the `updateBoard` function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 100

void command(int argc) {
    if (argc != 3) { // Takes in 3 arguments. File name/Size/Number of letters
        printf("You need 3 arguments");
    } else {
    }
}

int args(char* arg) {
    int size;
    size = atoi(arg); // Convert string to int
    return size; // Return int
}

int checkBoard(char myArray[MAX][MAX], int size) {
    int i, j; // Loop through board
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (myArray[i][j] == myArray[i + 1][j] &&
                myArray[i + 1][j] == myArray[i + 2][j]) {
                myArray[i][j] = ' '; // Change 3 cells to blanks
                myArray[i + 1][j] = ' ';
                myArray[i + 2][j] = ' ';
            }
            if (myArray[i][j] == myArray[i][j + 1] &&
                myArray[i][j + 1] == myArray[i][j + 2]) {
                myArray[i][j] = ' '; // Change cells to blanks
                myArray[i][j + 1] = ' ';
                myArray[i][j + 2] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    int pass2;
    pass2 = updateBoard(myArray, size); // Pass array board to next function

    updateBoard(myArray, size);
}

int updateBoard(char myArray[MAX][MAX], int size) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) // Loops through and prints board
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (myArray[i][j] == ' ' && myArray[i + 1][j] == ' ' &&
                myArray[i + 2][j] == ' ') {
                myArray[i][j] =
                    myArray[i][j - 1]; // Drop cell if existing cells are blank
                myArray[i + 1][j] = myArray[i][j - 1];
                myArray[i + 2][j] = myArray[i][j - 1];
            }
            if (myArray[i][j] == ' ' && myArray[i][j + 1] == ' ' &&
                myArray[i][j + 2] == ' ') {
                myArray[i][j] = myArray[i][j - 4]; // Same as above
                myArray[i][j + 1] = myArray[i][j - 4];
                myArray[i][j + 2] = myArray[i][j - 4];
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) // Loop through and print updated board
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            printf("%c ", myArray[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    int flag;
    if (myArray[MAX][MAX]) {
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        flag = 0;
    }

    while (flag != 1) {
        int pass3;
        pass3 = checkBoard(myArray, size);
        checkBoard(myArray, size);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i, j;
    int size, sarg; // Two arguments

    command(argc); // Call command function

    printf("test1\n");
    size = args(argv[1]); // Passing arguments
    printf("test2\n");
    sarg = args(argv[2]);
    printf("test3\n");
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", argv[2]);
    printf("Arg1: %d\nArg2: %d\n\n", size, sarg);

    srand(time(NULL)); // Use of time to generate random characters

    static char myArray[MAX][MAX];
    char letter =
        'A' + (rand() % sarg); // 26 possible letters for second argument

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            myArray[i][j] = 'a' + (rand() % sarg); // Loop through and fill
                                                   // board
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            printf("%c ", myArray[i][j]); // Loop through and print board
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    int pass; // Pass initial board to checkboard function
    pass = checkBoard(myArray, size);

    int count;

    checkBoard(myArray, size); // Call function to generate updated board

    printf("The number of moves made is %d: ", count);
}
```

***PS:*** The count in main is supposed to increment every time the board drops cells to count the number moves that have been made. Any advice on how to count the number of times a function has been executed? Cheers

Comment: To improve this question, you should highlight or only show the part of the code that appears to not be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an endless loop if the value of flag is not 1.

```
 while(flag != 1){
        int pass3;
        pass3 = checkBoard(myArray,size);
        checkBoard(myArray,size);
    }
```

Comment: How would I go about fixing it?

Comment: I don't know what your program does and what it should be supposed to do. You will learn best if you try to solve it yourself. I pointed where the problem is and now you try to solve it. That way you will learn best. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question on how to count the number of times a function has been executed, declare a `static` local variable initialized to 0 in the function, and increment it once like so:

```
int foo() {
   static int count = 0;
   count++;
   // Rest of the function here
}
```

The `static` variable is initialized to 0 when the program is first run and maintains its value between function calls -- it is not re-initialized every time the function is called. Since it is incremented in each function call it counts the number of calls.

It's a local variable so you'll have to put a breakpoint in your program and look at its value in a debugger, or provide a way for the function to return the value so the rest of the program can read its value.